# Axios (React Native) POST request working on iOS (emulator) but not on Android (emulator)

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, axios, expo

Please help me, I'm so stuck on this problem:
I'm making an Async request with Axios on React Native and the request is working correctly only within the iOS emulator, but it is not working with the Android emulator (403 Forbidden response).

The request that I'm doing is:

```
const signIn = dispatch => async ({ email, password }) => {
try {
    const response = await authApi.post('/login', ({ email, password }));
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}};
```

Where authApi is:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://dev.lyribooks.com/api/api/auth',
    withCredentials: true,
    crossdomain: true,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you activate the debug js option  in Android device react native context menu?

Answer (score 0):

@Oleg Thank u so much for the suggestion.. probably was a wrong server configuration blocking my request, because after I've added my useragent in whitelist all it's working fine now.